# Drupal one time login page

Tags: drupal-7

Having a little issue with something that seems so simple!

After clicking the one time login link a user is taken to a page displaying -

"This is a one-time login for dean and will expire on Thu, 06/06/2013 - 14:27.

Click on this button to log in to the site and change your password.

This login can be used only once."

I want to change the date format to Long, but can't figure it out...

Can anyone shed any light on this? Using Drupal 7

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Under Configuration >> People >> Account settings, find the places where the token [user:one-time-login-url] is used.  Append */login*, so the token looks like

**[user:one-time-login-url]/login**.

Additional detail on [Dave Cohen's blog](http://www.dave-cohen.com/node/1000020).